# ValueError: The provided lr scheduler "<torch.optim.lr_scheduler.MultiStepLR object at 0x0000021897D84160>" is invalid

Tags: pytorch, scheduler, pytorch-lightning

I encountered this error when I tried to NERF with the GPU, and this error occurred in train.fit() where the trainer is as follow:

```
    from pytorch_lightning import LightningModule, Trainer
    trainer = Trainer(max_epochs=hparams.num_epochs,
                      callbacks=callbacks,
                      resume_from_checkpoint=hparams.ckpt_path,
                      logger=logger,
                      enable_model_summary=False,
                      accelerator='auto',
                      devices=hparams.num_gpus,
                      # gpus=-1,
                      num_sanity_val_steps=1,
                      benchmark=True,
                      profiler="simple" if hparams.num_gpus==1 else None,
                      strategy=DDPPlugin(find_unused_parameters=False) if hparams.num_gpus>1 else None)

    trainer.fit(system)
```

I don't know what to do with the problem, and i sincerely need your help, thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that MultiStepLR is invalid in LightningModule.I met the same error and fixed it by replace MultiStepLR by a ReduceLROnPlateau.

```
optim_conf = model.configure_optimizers()
monitor = "val_loss"
a,b = optim_conf
scheduler0 = ReduceLROnPlateau(a[0])
b[0]=scheduler0
```

where a is a list of Adam optimizer,b is also a list and b[0] is MultiStepLR.
Hope this could help.